# UUID which version to use to avoid collisions

Tags: guid, uuid

In my system, people use different devices (which works online and offline) to create entries(stored locally until synced) and they get synced with other devices and the server periodically. For this reason, I have to use UUID so that each device can generate a UUID to identify a record and subrecords under it so that it can be synced with other devices once it's synced with the server. So far, it's working well. The only problem is that I got a collision. Even though there are only 400k records in the system, I am wondering this could happen more often.

I am using https://github.com/monicao/angular-uuid4 version 4. Should I use version 1 instead? Each device usually generate none to few UUID per minute, so no chance of split second generation on a single device. These UUID will always be generated from client side and not by server side.

What is the best way to reduce the chance of collisions here assuming no evil/malicious clients and the UUID is system generated and it doesn't matter if it can be traced?

Comment: The documentation reports collisions due to `Math.random()` not working properly.  In this case, you might want to use a different library.  FYI there are roughly `1 x 10^50` unique UUIDs which the library can generate, so if they were truly being generated randomly, then 400K devices is nothing to worry over.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Actually the devices are only few hundreds. The actual table rows are 400k. Do you recommend any client side UUID library to be used in browser which are truly random? Do you think this will suffice https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with these client side libraries, but regardless of any answer you should test this library to make sure it works in production.

Comment: Surely, I think they are used in production already. But I am not sure whether v1 or v4 will have less chance of colliding theoretically if the devices generate the UUID are different and they are mostly Ipads.

Comment: No...you are heading down the wrong path now.  If the UUIDs be truly random, then statistically speaking you can ignore the chance of collision.  But the v4 library has problems which result in the UUIDs generated not being truly random.  You need to _test_ each library and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the implementation of the library you are using.

Since you are already storing ids with 128 bit precision (stored as 16 chars, not the 36 chars used to encode as a string with hexadecimal values and dashes), you can simply use this for your id generator:

```js
// Returns a 128 bit random id encoded as hexadecimal values.
string randomId() {
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(16)
  crypto.getRandomBytes(bytes)
  return Array.from(bytes, b => ('0' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('')
}
```

But this is [bad for your database](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/11/22/uuids-are-popular-but-bad-for-performance-lets-discuss/) so to improve things, you can use a number of bytes to add locality:

```js
const LOCALITY_BYTES = 4
const RESOLUTION = 500 // [ms]
// 4 bytes with 500 ms resolution gives 68 years modulo.
const MODULO = Math.pow(2, LOCALITY_BYTES * 8)

function locality() {
  let date = Math.floor(Date.now() / RESOLUTION) % MODULO
  const bytes = []
  for (let i = 0; i < LOCALITY_BYTES; ++i) {
    const b = date % 256
    bytes.unshift(b)
    date = (date - b) / 256
  }
  return bytes
}

function randomIdWithLocality() {
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(16)
  crypto.getRandomValues(bytes)
  bytes.set(locality())
  return Array.from(bytes, b => ('0' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('')
}
```

With this implementation, you have "only" 96 bits of randomness per 500 ms timeframe compared to v4 122 bits (for the whole life of your app). These 96 bits give you a 50% chance of having at least 1 collision if you write 3 * 10^14 records in 500 ms instead of v4's 2.6 * 10^18 for your app's duration [v4 uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions).